# sqlalchemy query.update fails with AttributeName error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This code fails and I do not understand why.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

engine = create_engine ( <connection string> )
meta = MetaData ( )
meta.reflect ( bind=engine )
session = sessionmaker ( )
session.configure ( bind=engine )

table = meta.tables['user']
s = session ( )
kwargs = {'employee_id': 'robbiee'}

s.query ( table ).filter_by ( **kwargs ).update ( {'home_email': 'my email yo'} )
s.commit ( )
```

The error is

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'class_'
```

I'm simply trying to update records in an existing database.  I could do it with raw sql, but trying to learn the sqlalchemy way.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit:
This expression works correctly.

```
for row in s.query ( table ).filter_by ( **kwargs ):
    print row
```

It's when the update() portion is added that it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same error(when updating using session) and couldn't resolved after many tries.

So, i used the following:

```
from sqlalchemy import update
u = update(table, table.c.employee_id == kwargs['employee_id'])
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(u, 'home_email': 'my email yo')
```